# Acces default @ConfigurationProperties property from thymeleaf

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf, spring-properties

I am trying to read a property using thymeleaf and I can't get it to work.
I have the following property class:

```
@Configuration
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "storage")
public class FileSystemStorageProperties {
    private String location = "image-dir";

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

And I am trying to read the location property in thymeleaf using

```
${@environment.getProperty('storage.location')}
```

however nothing is displayed.

EDIT:
If I set `storage.location=to something else` in *application.properties*, it works. But why doesn't thymeleaf pick the default value??

Comment: What do you mean with it doesn't pick the default value? The value in the `application.properties` or in your `@Configuration` class?

Comment: The default value is `image-dir`. Thymeleaf doesn't see it. However, when manually setting that value inside the `application.properties`, Thymeleaf picks it. EDIT: the value in my `@Configuration`

Comment: I edited my answer for that.

Comment: @dan1st I am still confused (I am new to Spring). Then what is the point of using `@ConfigurationProperties` in the first place?

Comment: It overwrites the local variables with the values from your `application.properties`

Comment: `@Value("${storage.location:image-dir}")` Try this annotation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring does not automatically load parameters based on the variable name.

You can just [annotate the getter method with `@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-javaconfig/docs/1.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch02s02.html) and name it the way you want the property to be named:

```java
@Bean
public String location() {
    return location;
}
```

If you want to name you getter method `getLocation()`, you can do that too by setting the [name of the `@Bean`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/Bean.html#name--):

```java
@Bean(name="location")
public String getLocation() {
    return location;
}
```

> If I set `storage.location=to something else` in `application.properties`, it works. But why doesn't thymeleaf pick the default value??

If you set the value in the `application.propererties`, spring recognizes that as property and uses it.

If not, spring thinks it is just a getter for something else.

Comment: I updated my question. Your answear works, but it's not what I intended.

Answer (score 1):

If you change your properties class to:

```
@Component("fileSystemStorageProperties") // Use @Component instead of @Configuration and give the bean an explicit name
@ConfigurationProperties(prefix = "storage")
public class FileSystemStorageProperties {
    private String location = "image-dir";

    public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }

    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

Then you can this in Thymeleaf:

```
${@fileSystemStorageProperties.location}
```

See https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/springmvcaccessdata.html#spring-beans for more info.